# Laravel get data from many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot

For a school project, I'm creating a website in the Laravel framework.
I can't work with the data from a many-to-many table in my controller.

Here are my models:

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
    public function Tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'items_has_tags', 'items_id', 'tags_id');
    }
}

class Tag extends Eloquent {
    public function LearningMaterials()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('LearningMaterial', 'learning_materials_has_tags', 'tags_id', 'learning_materials_id');
    }
}
```

I want to iterate all tags from my items in my controller:

```
//get all items
$all = Item::where('public', '1')->get();

foreach($allLm as $item){
     $tags = $item->Tags();

     var_dump('will iterate');

     foreach($tags as $t){
         var_dump('will not iterate');
     }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I handle the tags from my items?

FYI: I'm creating a search engine. If the user inserts an input value like "mana", all items with tag "management" should be shown.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Laravel's `belongsToMany` method **queries** related models and doesn't get them. That's because you might want to have some additional constraints in your query. What you need to do is:

```
$tags = $item->Tags()->get();
```

Or simply:

```
$tags = $item->Tags;
```

Comment: and how to get like the tag name ?

Comment: @mercury it's a collection, so you need to loop over it, or map it etc.

Answer (score 9):

Calling the relationship function will return a **relation object** (in this case an instance of `BelongsToMany`). You can use this to run add further components to your query before running it.
For example:

```
$only4Tags = $item->Tags()->take(4)->get();
```

If you want the **result** of your relation, call `get()` or simpler, just use the magic property:

```
$tags = $item->Tags()->get();
$tags = $item->Tags;
```

Comment: How would you do it for specific Tags IDs (that come from an array)?

Comment: @Pathros would you even need a relation then? You could just query them like `Tag::find([1, 2, 3])` if you have the ids.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to find out that I can use `->whereHas()` and then `->whereIn()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36593847/1883256).

Comment: Thanks, it also works for what I was looking for: `$onlyOneTag = $item->Tags()->take(1)->first()`