# Laravel eloquent get all records wherehas all ids in many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a `Posts` table it has three fields `id`, `title`, `description`.

My `Post` Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag');
    }
}
```

My `Tag` Model

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_tag');
    }
}
```

Now I want to get posts & paginate where I have a tag filter e.g I have two tags `animals` & `news` which has id `1` & `2`. Now I want to get all posts which has tag `1` & `2` & `paginate`. Here is what I tried

```
        Post:: with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) {
            $q->whereIn('id', [1, 2]);
        })->paginate();
```

But here as I am `whereIn` it returns posts has tags `1` or `2` or `both`. But I want post who has both tag id 1 & 2.

I am using `Laravel 5.2`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to loop through your list of ids to add that condition, then. For instance:

```
$query =  Post::with('tags');
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    });
}
$query->paginate();
```

Comment: thanks @Joel it worked for me I will give an up vote but as I am looping over it I will wait for a better answer. thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking for the same thing and inspired by [this stackoverflow MySQL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650786/get-all-entries-from-table-b-which-have-a-relation-to-multiple-entries-given-li#26652551), I have ended up with this

**Code:**

```
Post:: with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) {
    $idList = [1,2];
    $q->whereIn('id', $idList)
      ->havingRaw('COUNT(id) = ?', [count($idList)])
})->paginate();
```

Because I think I might use it in a few places I have made it into a trait which you can [view here](https://gist.github.com/TheoKouzelis/760950040dbc0073f36c2664a88fac05). Which if you included the trait in your Post class you could use like the following.

**Code:**

```
Post::with('tags')->whereHasRelationIds('tags', [1,2])->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use whereHas()'s third and fourth parameter in combination with `whereIn():`

```php
$keys = [1, 2];

$list->whereHas(
    'genres',
    fn ($query) => $query->whereIn('id', $keys),
    '=',
    count($keys)
);
```

Comment: Adding some explanation of what these parameters do would make this answer more helpful. And what is `$list` or "genres"? Please tailor your answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a built in method for this, but I would suggest putting the foreach loop inside the whereHas method just for neatness sake.

```
$query = Post::with('tags')->wherehas('tags', function ($q) use ($ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    }
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Did you tried this @alexleonard? I have tried this earlier it didn't work.

Comment: This will never work because 'id' cannot be two values at the same time. Your subquery will return something like SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id = 1 and id = 2;