# Many to Many Get All Id Function Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Is there a function to get All the item_id in Many to Many relations.
[image]

```
$subcategory = $this->subcategory->find($id);
```

Or Do I need to do it manually. Basically I can do it but I hope there is an aggregate function.

```
$itemIds=[];
foreach($subcategory->items as $item){
  $itemIds[] = $item->id;
}
```

Comment: Answer of your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593847/laravel-eloquent-get-all-records-wherehas-all-ids-in-many-to-many-relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need. Btw try to research before asking

```
$item_ids = $subcategory->items->pluck('id');
```

Comment: I did already a research but haven't found it, that's the reason why I asked it here. But anyway thanks, it cost you a lot.

Comment: If answer is ok, vote up and accept answer are always appriciated